# Associate pairs of data

Tags: plotting, associations

What I want is to associate  the pairs of a nested list, like this:  `Association[{11 -> DateObject[{2019, 6, 4}, "Day", "Gregorian", -5.]}... ]`  and so on.

So when a plot it with the `TimeLinePlot` I would get something like the picture,  and when I pass the cursor over the number I would get the date.[image: 1]

Here is the whole nested list:

```
dates = {{11, DateObject[{2019, 6, 4}, "Day", "Gregorian", -5.]}, 
           {22, DateObject[{2019, 6, 6}, "Day", "Gregorian", -5.]}, 
           {33, DateObject[{2019, 6, 7}, "Day", "Gregorian", -5.]}, 
           {41, DateObject[{2019, 6, 1}, "Day", "Gregorian", -5.]}, 
           {53, DateObject[{2019, 6, 8}, "Day", "Gregorian", -5.]}, 
           {63, DateObject[{2019, 6, 8}, "Day", "Gregorian", -5.]}, 
           {72, DateObject[{2019, 6, 6}, "Day", "Gregorian", -5.]}, 
           {38, DateObject[{2019, 6, 9}, "Day", "Gregorian", -5.]}, 
           {92, DateObject[{2019, 6, 21}, "Day", "Gregorian", -5.]}, 
           {130, DateObject[{2019, 6, 26}, "Day", "Gregorian", -5.]}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
TimelinePlot[Association[Rule @@@ dates]]
```

... or alternatively:

```
TimelinePlot[AssociationThread[dates[[All, 1]] -> dates[[All, 2]]]]
```

Comment: Or `TimelinePlot@Association[Rule @@@ dates]`.

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi I already did that in the edit